# GoLang: Update file that is served by FileServer

Tags: go, fileserver

I am serving a directory using FileServer as follows:

```
go func() {
  fs := http.FileServer(http.Dir("./view"))
  err := http.ListenAndServe(":8000", fs)
  if err != nil {
    log.Fatal("ListenAndServe: ", err)
  }
}()
```

Inside the `view` directory I have an `index.html` file, which I am trying to update while the `view` directory is being served. I observe that the append commands block and update the file only after I stop serving the directory.

Below is the code to modify the file:

```
func AppendToFile() {
  f, err := os.OpenFile("./view/index.html", os.O_RDWR, 0644)
  if err != nil {
    panic(err)
  }
  defer f.Close()
  // This assumes that the file ends with </body></html>
  f.Seek(-15, 2)
  if _, err = f.WriteString("test test test\n"); err != nil {
    panic(err)
  }
  if _, err = f.WriteString("</body></html>\n"); err != nil {
    panic(err)
  }
}
```

Is this the expected behavior?

Thank you!

Comment: You're not showing the code to modify the file.

Comment: @Marc It is just a simple `WriteString` at the end of the file.

Comment: You don't show how you are calling `AppendToFile()`. See @sigkilled 's answer - as the function should be able to update the file without issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http.FileServer function just returns a handler. So it is not blocking the filesystem.
The problem in here might be related with the offset of your file. I've tried in my machine and it worked without any problem.

I've modified your code to this;

```
package main

import (
    "net/http"
    "os"
    "time"
)

func main() {
    t := time.NewTicker(time.Second)
    defer t.Stop()
    go func() {
        srv := http.FileServer(http.Dir("./test"))
        http.ListenAndServe(":8080", srv)
    }()

    for {
        select {
        case <-t.C:
            appendToFile()
        }
    }
}

func appendToFile() {
    f, err := os.OpenFile("./test/index.html", os.O_RDWR, 0644)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    defer f.Close()
    // This assumes that the file ends with </body></html>
    f.Seek(-16, 2)
    if _, err = f.WriteString("test test test\n"); err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    if _, err = f.WriteString("</body></html>\n"); err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
}
```

In index.html I put blank document initially,

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>

</body></html>
```

PS: It is better to check offset of  first, then write the string to that position.

Comment: thanks for taking the time required to reproduce OP code. I felt lazy to deal with the timeouts myself to hit the browser, so integrated the whole thing for simpler testing experience https://play.golang.org/p/cgzuP2r1Qlx

Comment: Thank you! It turns out the problem was completely unrelated to this. (I'm relatively new to Go.) I really appreciate your help!

Comment: You are welcome.